# Are infinite loops handled in Frama-C?

Tags: frama-c

I am trying to prove that the value of a variable always increases. I have written the following code:

```
void Commit() {
    int count = 1;
    //@ ghost int old_count = 0;

    while (1) {
        //@ ghost old_count = count;
        count++;
        //@ assert count > old_count;
    }
}

int main () {
    Commit();
    return 0;
}
```

I then use the command : `frama-c -val file.c` but the assertion status remains unknown. Am I missing something extremely basic here? Or are infinite loops not handled by Frama-C?

Answer (score 4):

There are two levels of answer to your question.

1) you want to prove a *relational* property between `old_count` and `count`. This kind of analysis is not available by default in Frama-C/Eva, and your assertion does not get proven. You can either:

- use deductive verification, as in this simple example you do not even need additional annotations. You can verify that `frama-c -wp` proves the assertion
- use the (experimental) relational domains of Frama-C/Eva, that are based on Apron. For technical reasons, those do not yet work on assertions, so you should rewrite your code in the following way:

  ```
  void Commit() {
      int count = 1;
      //@ ghost int old_count = 0;

      while (1) {
          //@ ghost old_count = count;
          count++;
          /*@ ghost
            int d = count - old_count;
            Frama_C_show_each(d);
          */
      }
  }
  ```

  The result of `frama-c -val -eva-apron-oct` is

  ```
  [value] /home/yakobowski/incr.c:10: Frama_C_show_each: {1}
  [value] /home/yakobowski/incr.c:5: starting to merge loop iterations
  [value] /home/yakobowski/incr.c:10: Frama_C_show_each: {1}
  [value] /home/yakobowski/incr.c:10: Frama_C_show_each: {1}
  [value:alarm] /home/yakobowski/incr.c:7: Warning: 
    signed overflow. assert count + 1 ≤ 2147483647;
  [value] /home/yakobowski/incr.c:10: Frama_C_show_each: {1}
  ```

  `d` always has value 1, which is the expected value. Without option `-eva-apron-oct`, you get

  ```
  [value] /home/yakobowski/incr.c:10: Frama_C_show_each: [-2147483645..2147483646]
  ```

  on the last iteration.

2) your example does not make sense from a verification standpoint, because there are no such things as ever-increasing variables in C. Your code is correct only as long as `count < 2147483647`. When instead they are equal, your code causes an undefined behavior, on the line `count++`. This is the reason for the alarm emitted by Eva on this line.

Please note that this fact does not invalidate the analysis I did in 1). All the reasoning done by either WP or Eva holds under the assumption that `count + 1 ≤ 2147483647` is true, which is not provable in your code.

Comment: Re point 2: I had included a check on count in the loop condition after seeing the warning from Frama-C (and realized the possibility of overflow) but I didn't include it in the question because I thought there maybe a work around without excluding it. Anyways, thanks for the answer, it is very useful.